# Stubbing out an instance of a class to test a callback given as an attribute

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm attempting to test a line of code in a `proc` see (`proc { |message| flash[:notice] << message }` in the code snippet below) using Rspec 3.9 but I can't seem to stub out the instance to do what I want.

Given the following controller and test, how can I stub out `CreateAccount` and run the `on_success` attribute given in the controller?

Here is the controller file

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        CreateAccount.new(
          on_success: proc { |message| flash[:notice] << message }
        ).process

        redirect_to action: :index
    end
end
```

Here is the Rspec test file

```
describe AccountsController, type: :controller do
    describe 'POST #create' do
        subject(:create_action) { post :create, id: 1 }

        let(:success_message) { 'Success!' }

        context 'when created account successfully' do
            it { is_expected.to redirect_to action: :index }
            it do
                create_action
                expect(flash[:notice]).to include success_message
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The reason I want to do this is to separate concerns from the controller to the `CreateAccount` object. It shouldn't matter, but here is the `CreateAccount` object so far.

```
class CreateAccount
    def initialize on_success: proc { |_| }
        @on_success = on_success
    end

    def call
        # Do some meaningful work
        success_message = 'Meaningful message'

        @on_success.call(success_message)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find 1 solution that works but I would like to know if there's a cleaner way

Note: The controller and `CreateAction` classes remain the same.

```
describe AccountsController, type: :controller do
    describe 'POST #create' do
        subject(:create_action) { post :create, id: 1 }

        context 'when created account successfully' do
            let(:dummy_class) do
                Class.new(CreateAction) do                
                    def call
                        @on_success.call(self.class.message)
                    end

                    def self.message
                        'Success!'
                    end
                end     
            end

            before { stub_constant 'CreateAction', dummy_class }

            it { is_expected.to redirect_to action: :index }
            it do
                create_action
                expect(flash[:notice]).to include dummy_class.message
            end
        end
    end
end
```